# Is an ultrapower of a faithful Banach algebra always faithful?

Tags: banach-algebras, ultrapowers

Let $A$  be an infinite dimensional faithful Banach algebra and let $\mathcal U$ be a free ultrafilter. Is the ultrapower $(A)_{\mathcal U}$ faithful?

Comment: Yes we can. Presumably you meant to ask: "is an ultrapower of a faithful Banach algebra always faithful?" and the answer is no.

Comment: You say "free ultrafilter", but probably intend to consider only ultrafilters concentrating on a countable index set, or at least non-$\sigma$-complete ultrafilters. After all, if there is a measurable cardinal, then one can have countably-complete ultrafilters, whose ultrapowers leave all small structures invariant, including your Banach algebra $A$, so that $A=(A)_U$. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This merely expands on my comment above.)

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra and let $L: A\to {\mathcal B}(A)$ be defined by $L(a)(x)=ax$. The map $L$ is a norm-decreasing homomorphism but it need not have closed range. (For instance, take $A=\ell^p$ with pointwise multiplication, for any $1\leq p <\infty$.)

So, let us suppose $L$ does not have closed range . Then there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that $\Vert a_n\Vert=1$ for all $n$ while $\Vert L(a_n) \Vert \to 0$.
Let $[a]$ be the element of the ultrapower that corresponds to the sequence $(a_n)$. Then clearly $[a]$ is a non-zero, left annihilator of any element of the ultrapower.